# Nothing showed on my Android's screen when I built my app in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening but I have an idea. I'm not sure what to do about it though. I've searched the internet but haven't gotten an exact answer. Here is an error that might help. (don't question the file names)

`Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"`

I tried searching the internet, looking at my catlog, etc. But I haven't found anything.

Nothing is showing on the screen of the app I built. Here is the code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.app.Activity
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button


class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.amogusfile)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.supabutton)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            mediaPlayer
        }
    }
}

const val url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KfC923EFsY" // your URL here
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
    setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
    )
    setDataSource(url)
    prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    start()
}
```

amogusfile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/supabutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/amogus"
        tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
    \
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you declare your `mediaPlayer` variable initializes it *and prepares and starts playing it* when the class is constructed, *before* `onCreate` is called.

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply { // Create MediaPlayer object when class is created

    // Also sets AudioAttributes

    setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
    )
    setDataSource(url)

    // Also calls prepare which, based on the comment, could take long and hang

    prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

    // Also STARTS the media - that can't be right
    start()
}
```

Meanwhile, your button click just references the variable. This does nothing.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    mediaPlayer
}
```

I'm assuming you want to, at minimum, not call `start()` until you click the button:

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
    setAudioAttributes(
        AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .build()
    )
    setDataSource(url)
    prepare() // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
}
```

Then:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    mediaPlayer.start()
}
```

You may also what to move the `prepare()` call, or use `prepareAsync()`.